# How can video software render so fast?

Tags: bitmap, rendering

I was creating some fractal renderer with low framerate, and noticed almost all processor time is being spent on drawing the (software) bitmap. How does video software like VLC and Windows Media Player do it? As they have to render 1080p+ images, with 24fps, while they do the rendering on the CPU.

Comment: I think you might find that the secret is they don't do the rendering on the CPU... :-D

Comment: But how do they get the data so fast from CPU to GPU?

Comment: you can just download the source and look at mplayer/vlc right? ffmpeg is generally doing the decoding, but that buffer gets blitted at some point I imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea, as is the idea with GPU accelerated graphics in general, is that the CPU just sends simple commands to the GPU and the GPU is then responsible for doing all the heavy lifting. Most modern GPUs are capable of decoding various video streams in hardware and other such useful things. Even the VideoCore in the Raspberry Pi is capable of playing high-definition video and the CPU in that is only a 600mhz single core chip.

Most OSes have a high level abstraction of this so you don't have to break out the whole OpenGL/Direct3D interface. On OS X this would be [Coure Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Concepts/CVProg_Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001536-CH202-BABJDFHJ) and on the Microsoft side there is the [Audio Video Playback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb324497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.